# Facebook Graph API batch POST_ID comment counts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-processing, facebook-comments

Facebook recently deprecated comment counts from being returned when you call a page feed.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=facebook%2Ffeed
```

They offer a work around that does not help my use case.

> Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection We are removing
>   the undocumented 'count' field on the 'comments' connection in the
>   Graph API. Please request '{id}/comments?summary=true' explicitly if
>   you would like the summary field which contains the count (now called
>   'total_count')

One can obtain a comment by searching for a specific POST_ID/comments and passing in the summary param

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=305115773870_10151638225723871%2Fcomments%3Fsummary%3Dtrue
```

The problem is I am managing hundreds of Pages, I need to obey rate limits, and I would like the comment count of every Post, from every page I manage. How is it possible to batch this operation?

Why did facebook decide to break this?

Answer (score 0):

> Why did facebook decide to break this?

You can use [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) to achieve this.

Since you want only the comment count, we will limit the number of comments returned to <del>1 (the minimum possible – 0 would mean no limit and therefor the default of 25(?))</del>, and ask for the `summary` field of the comments as well:

[/facebook/feed?fields=comments.limit(0).summary(1)](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=facebook%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dcomments.limit(1).summary(1)%26limit%3D3)

Only slight drawback: Since this is using the `fields` parameter, you have to specify *other* fields of the post object you want to get as well – `id` and `created_time` are included by default as you can see, but others as f.e. `message` you will have to specify explicitly if you want to get them returned too.

---

Edit: Using `.limit(0)` is now possible directly. You will still get a `data` structure below `comments`, but it will be empty.